# exit shell script from subshell if files are not present on remote server or disk is full?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, gnu-parallel

I am using below script to copy files in parallel from remote server:

```
#!/bin/bash

primary=/bat/primary
secondary=/bat/secondary

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  primsec=$2
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
   goldy@"$remote":"$pod1"/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)\
  || \
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
   goldy@"$remote":"$pod2"/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)\
  || \
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
   goldy@"$remote":"$pod3"/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)\
  || \
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
   goldy@"$remote":"$pod4"/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)
}
export -f do_copy

parallel -j "$5" do_copy {} $primary ::: ${pri[@]} &
parallel -j "$5" do_copy {} $secondary ::: ${snd[@]} &
wait
echo "all files copied"
```

On the remote server I have four folders represented by `$pod1`, `$pod2`, `$pod3`, `$pod4`. If files are not there in `$pod1`, then it should be there in `$pod2`, or it will be there in `$pod3` or it will be there in `$pod4` folder.

Now what I want to do is:

- If files are not there in any of those four folders then I want to exit from shell script with nonzero status code immediately.
- If for whatever reason let's say disk is full and file were not copied fully then I want to exit as well with nonzero status code. Each file size is around 15GB and sometimes because of disk full, I see only 3GB copied out of 15GB and my shell script don't report any issues and passes successfully.

I tried adding `exit` command next to last `scp` command but it just exits from the subshell not from whole script. Is there any way to do these things?

Comment: If `$pod1` *et al* contain no spaces then all four checks can be done in a loop:  `for p in $pod{1..4}; do scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
   goldy@"$remote":"$f"/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/. && break; done > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: yeah its a good suggestion. thanks for your help! Any idea about my two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the file exists on only one pod, so trying all pods is not a problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

primary=/bat/primary
secondary=/bat/secondary

# Activate parset and env_parallel if not already done
. `which env_parallel.bash`

# Make array with $primary as many times as elements in $pri
parset prim -N0 echo $primary ::: ${pri[@]} 
# Make array with $secondary as many times as elements in $pri
parset seco -N0 echo $secondary ::: ${sec[@]}
export remote

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  primsec=$2
  pod=$3
  scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
   goldy@"$remote":"$pod"/abc_187_"$el"_111_8.data "$primsec"/
}
export -f do_copy
copy_one_file() {
  parallel do_copy $1 $2 ::: pod{1..4}
  if [ $? == 4 ] ; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}
export -f copy_one_file
parallel --halt now,fail=1 copy_one_file :::  ${pri[@]} ${sec[@]} :::+ ${prim[@]} ${seco[@]}
```

`parset` makes an array with `$primary` as long as `$pri`.

`:::+` links the elements from `$pri` to the elements in `$prim`.

You will need parallel version > 20170422 for `parset`.